# LDAP Integration for Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap

I'm very new to AWS env, need your help on below

We are exploring LDAP Integration for Amazon Redshift.
Unable to find the right documentation/process, Can anyone has done ?

And found the doc related to Federated Authentication ( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/federate-database-user-authentication-easily-with-iam-and-amazon-redshift/ ), What is the difference between this and LDAP integration?

Also LDAP integration requires SSO enabling ?

Please share your thoughts.
Thanks